# Passing environment variable in bash script for the value which need to have double quotes

Tags: json, bash, curl, special-characters

I'm working on a bash script and have a curl cmd :

```
curl -u root:$pass -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://$ip/nitro/ \
  -d '{"user":{"username":"test","password":"test123" }}' -k
```

For password test123 in the above curl cmd, i want to pass it as an environment variable. 
Have tried following ways but it isn't working.

```
curl -u root:$pass -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://$ip/nitro/ \
  -d '{"user":{"username":"test","password":$new_pswrd }}' -k

curl -u root:$pass -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://$ip/nitro/ \
  -d '{"user":{"username":"test","password":\"$new_pswrd\" }}' -k
```

Please suggest what could be wrong here, and how can I escape double quotes in post JSON parameter for curl cmd  ?

Comment: You are placing the argument of the `-d` flat between single quotes. Hence, `$new_pswrd` won't be expanded, but passed literally to curl.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
[STEP 101] $ pass=test123
[STEP 102] $ echo '{"user":{"username":"test","password":"'"$pass"'" }}'
{"user":{"username":"test","password":"test123" }}
[STEP 103] $
```

(This would not work if the password includes chars like `"`. I don't know the syntax for JSON to escape `"` and other special chars so I cannot comment more.)

Comment: You'd either escape a double quote with a backslash or use `\u0020`.

Answer (score 0):

You used single quotes. Bash allows two different quoting mechanisms:

Single quote: Everything enclosed is literal.
Double quotes: Interpret $ and \, pass the rest as literal.

Your bash environment variable $new_pswrd is in single quotes and will NOT be expanded, but will be passed as a dollar sign and the letters new_pswrd.

There are two way to achieve your goal:

Using single quotes: 'End the single quote '"and put your $variable in double quotes"' and bash will concatenate all of the strings '" because they lack white space between "" the open and close quotes "_or_lack_white_space_entirely.

Using double quotes: "A backslash will be interpreted when inside \"double quotes\" and the backslash will cause the following character, even it it is a double quote, to be pass through without closing the literal \". Dollar signs will be expanded and $shell_variable will be replaced with its value while \$shell_variable will not."